# How to implement WordCloud NPM in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**Hi!
I already added the WordCloud module to my project. Yet, I face a lot of problems when trying to at least show the simplest word cloud. I don't know what I'm doing wrong...**

**home.ts code:**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

    import { WordCloud } from 'wordcloud';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

      list = [['foo', 12], ['bar', 6]];

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      }

      WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );

    }
```

**home.html code:**

```
    <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
          Ionic Blank
        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>
      <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
    </ion-content>
```

**HELP PLEASE && THANK YOU**

I'm utilizing this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordcloud

Comment: Which specific problem do you have?

Comment: It brings me errors. I was able to add the word cloud module to my project. Then when I try to show it, it doesn't allow me.                                   Typescript Error
',' expected.
src/pages/home/home.ts
 WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );

Comment: The errors do not make any sense to me. I made a blank project in ionic and literally only added the code I included in my question above. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I guess you installed the npm packages wordcloud and @types/wordcloud, right?

Comment: Yes I did. It's also giving this error: Typescript Error
File .../Ionic App/testApp/node_modules/@types/wordcloud/index.d.ts' is not a module.
src/pages/home/home.ts
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WordCloud } from 'wordcloud';